# react-stomp only working in debug mode in React-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, websocket, stomp, spring-websocket

I am using react-stomp for subscribing stomp connection but it is only working in debug mode

```
import SockJsClient from 'react-stomp';
 

<View>
<SockJsClient
      url={STAMP_URL}
      topics={stamp_topic}
      onMessage={onMessageReceive} />
  </View>
```

Comment: `ws` or `wss`??